# What of these responses to this sql query, is more correct as per the sql specification?

Tags: mysql, sql

What of these responses to this sql query, is more correct as per the sql specification?

Here is the response from the later mysql version

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.11\bin>mysql.exe --version
mysql.exe  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.11, for Win32 (AMD64)

mysql> select * from blah6;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    6 |    8 |
|    7 |    8 |
|    9 |    3 |
|    6 |    3 |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select sum(col1),col2 from blah6;
+-----------+------+
| sum(col1) | col2 |
+-----------+------+
|        28 |    8 |
+-----------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

vs

Here, the response from an earlier mysql version

```
C:\wamp\mysql\bin>mysql.exe --version
mysql.exe  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.27, for Win32 (ia32)

mysql> select * from asdf2;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    5 |    6 |
|    9 |    3 |
|   29 |   13 |
|   44 |   13 |
|   44 |   53 |
|    5 |   33 |
+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select sum(col1),col2 from asdf2;
ERROR 1140 (42000): Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

Comment: The first one shouldn't be allowed ever, but well....mysql

Comment: @Lamak can you quote the spec to prove that? (with explanation since the spec is very mathematical)

Comment: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/sql-in-a/9780596155322/ch04s02.html

Comment: Here you go  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: As @lamak properly said, your first example shows how truly horrific it is that MySQL would allow you to have a column outside of an aggregate formula in your SELECT clause, that isn't also included in your GROUP BY. MySQL just grabs the first value it comes across in storage for that column which is nonsense.

Comment: Also, I was under the impression that version of MySQL before 5.7 allowed it by default, but the default was changed in 5.7 and newer. My MythWeb server borked when I upgraded because some thoughtful contributor had a statement or two written like this.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 has reeled in some of the more egregious MySQL-isms present in their particular SQL dialect. A lot of the "Do What I Mean" interpretations are gone because that tendency to do *whatever* would lead to unpredictability. For example, silent truncation, arbitrary default orderings, and other minor things are all gone.

Answer (score 0):

The comments cover the salient points:  The first is a (mis)feature in MySQL that causes confusion and generally encourages bad coding practices.  The error is the correct behavior.

I want to point out that this has nothing to do with the MySQL version.  Both operate the same way.  The question is whether the model `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is set.  When this mode is set, then MySQL better follows the ANSI standard for aggregation queries (read about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)).

Note:  this mode might be set using the more comprehensive `ANSI` mode.